# Why is for-loop variable skipping every second row when iterating over sqlite database?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, sqlite, output

I have set-up a sqlite database which records some world-trading data.
I am iterating over the database and want to extract some data, which will flow into another method of that class (works - no problem).

However, iterating over the database I have two variables "row" & "l":

> > For Row in Database("..."): 
> >     l = self.c.fetchone()

Strangely half of the data is in the variable "row" and the other half is in "l". It took me for ever to figure out, but now I really have no idea, why this problem happens? If I iterate over a list/db for "row" - "row" should have all the data for each iteration?

I tried accessing row through "row" and "l" from different ways, from within a new loop - rewrote the loops and restructured them, but then I have too much data and over 2000 entry points??? I used fetchmany() - and made another (outside) loop to iterate over,...

```
for row in self.c.execute("SELECT order_number,quotaStart,valid FROM volume"):
            l = self.c.fetchone()
            count+=1
            print(count,">>",row)
            print(count,">>",l)
```

I expect the data to be accessible through "row" or "l" - but not one half in one variable and the other half in the other?

Comment: Try deleting `l = self.c.fetchone()` and just using `row`

Comment: if you loop over the result, each iteration steps ahead one row. `fetchone` also steps ahead one row.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up 2 different ways of accessing the results of your query.  The simplest way to do it is:

```
for row in self.c.execute("SELECT order_number,quotaStart,valid FROM volume"):
    print(count, ">>", row)
```

Or alternatively:

```
self.c.execute("SELECT order_number,quotaStart,valid FROM volume"):
while l = self.c.fetchone():
    print(count, ">>", l)
```